# Solaris process taking up large CPU

Tags: solaris

I have a java process seens like taking up all the cpu processing power.
I thinking of killing it but how do i know what is the program that is actually causing such huge usage of solarsi cpu usage?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This question belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Admins please move this to superuser...

Answer (score 3):

Try [prstat](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/prstat.html) -- it should show you how much CPU each process on your system is using.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked sometime back, I'm posting this so anyone can refer in future.

You can use the `top` command to investigate the issue. However, the thing with Solaris is, you have to turn off the **Irix** mode to get the real process information. While running `top` tool, press **I** to toggle the **Irix** mode. 
More information can find here -> [How to investigate CPU utilization in Solaris](https://devreads.xyz/how-to-investigate-high-cpu-utilization-of-java-processes/)

Comment: Solaris also has prstat, which is similar to top (Curses style screen output periodically updated).